# How to use fscanf, care about endofline?

Tags: c, file, scanf

I want to read int from a file

The first line is composed of 1 int and the second of 2

ie

```
 1
 2 3
```

if i do

```
 fscanf(FILE, "%d \n %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
```

I obtain correctly the 3 numbers
but if i  put all the numbers on the same line in the file
ie `1 2 3`

I obtain the same result (and that's not what i want)

I want to know : How to force the user to go to a new line in his file ?

Edit :
As it seems unclear to some (i'm sorry for that) i want that the file

```
1 
2 3
```

Produce the result :

```
a = 1
b = 2 
c = 3
```

And the file

```
1 2 3
```

produce either an error or

```
a = 1
b = 0
c = 0
```

Comment: Its quite unclear what you want .

Comment: You're unclear here, If you are reading data from a file that is newline '\n' delimited then you need a loop that can call fgets(), as long as there isn't binary data in the file.  Post the the rest of your program so we can get an idea of the end goal here.

Comment: `int a, b, c; char temp[2]; if(fscanf(FILE, "%d%c%d%c%d", &a, &temp[0], &b, &temp[1], &c) != 5 || temp[0] != '\n' || temp[1] != ' '){ /* Invalid format of data in the file */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fscanf(FILE, "%d", ...);` first scans and discard white space before scanning for `int` characters.  In scanning white-space, both `' '` and `'\n'` are treated the same, so using `'%d'` loses the end-of-line.

`fscanf(FILE, "\n", ...);` and `fscanf(FILE, " ", ...);` do the same thing:  scan and discard *any* white space.  Using "\n" does *not* scan only for `'\n'`.

Code could use `fscanf(FILE, "%d%*1[\n]%d %d", &a, &b, &c) == 3`, to find a `'\n'` after `a`, but additional `'\n'` could be lurking in other places.

The only way using `scanf()` family to detect a `'\n'` involves using `'%c'` or `'%[]'` or `'%n'`.  It is easier to use `fgets()` and then parse with `sscanf()` or `strtol()`.

```
int Read1and2int(FILE *stream, int *a, int *b, int *c) {
   char buf[100];
   int n;

   if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stream) == NULL) return EOF;
   int count = sscanf(buf,"%d %n", a, &n);
   // Non-numeric or extra data
   if (count != 1 || buf[n]) return 0;

   if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stream) == NULL) return 1;
   count = sscanf(buf,"%d%d %n", b, c, &n);
   // Non-numeric or extra data
   if (count != 2 || buf[n]) return 1;
   return 3; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to read each line into a char buffer using `fgets` and parse each line with its own `sscanf`. You can use an extra `%s` on the end of the format string (and an extra pointer argument to a dummy variable of type `char *`) to detect whether the line contains extra stuff after the fields you're looking for.

Comment: I've never figured out why people continue to teach [f]scanf which, upon error, leaves the input stream in a virtually unknown state. fgets and sscanf is the way to separate reading from parsing.